# How do I limit the amount of values in a list - Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have written a program that asks the user 5 random maths questions and will save their name and score to a csv file.

I only want my list to store the latest 3 scores for each student. How can I do that in a list with Python 3?

The code I currently have is:

```
import csv

print ("Welcome to the teacher view.\n"
       "Here you can view the test results.\n")

option = int(input("Which class would you like view?\n"
                    "For Class 1 - enter 1: \n"
                    "For Class 2 - enter 2: \n"
                    "For Class 3 - enter 3: \n"))

if option ==1:
    with open("classthree.csv")as classone:
        classoneReader = csv.reader(classone)
        classonelist=[]
        for row in classoneReader:
            row[1] = int(row[1])
            classonelist.append(row[0:2])
    print(classonelist)
```

An example of the code that I have stored in a csv file is:

Josh Hill   8
Lisa Hale   7
Max Wood    10
Sally Jones 5
David West  2

The program should read this information and append it to a list. I would like to display the latest 3 scores for each student.

Comment: We will need more information than that, what is the code you currently have? How are you currently storing the scores?

Comment: Update in the question please.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between what your code produces and what you want it to?

Comment: Currently my code will append all of the contents from the csv file to a list called calssonelist. I would like it to only show me the latest 3)

Comment: show an example of your input file

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: There is only one score for each?

Comment: Yes I know. At the moment I cant even display just the last 3 in a list.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a deque, setting `maxlen=3` so you only keep the 3 latest:

```
from collections import deque

deq = deque(maxlen=3)
```

If you want to actually keep the latest three scores in a file you will need to update the scores by overwriting, if that is the case using a dict with json might be an easier way to store the data, using keys to access the students scores.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to fetch the last 3 scores from the list? [Slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) is the answer:

```
>>>mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>>mylist[-3:]
[4,5,6]
```

This is assuming you are using `append` as the method for growing the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had more than 1 score per student in the data file, for example:

```
Josh Hill,8,4,0,1,2
Lisa Hale,7,6,3,4,5
Max Wood,10,12,6,7,8
Sally Jones,5,5,9,10,11
David West,2,8,12,13,14
```

You could extract the last three scores from each row using [slice syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) as follows:

```
import csv

with open("classthree.csv", newline='') as classone:
    classoneReader = csv.reader(classone)
    classonelist=[]
    for row in classoneReader:
        row[1:] = list(map(int, row[1:]))  # convert scores to integers
        classonelist.append([row[0]] + row[-3:])

print('classonelist:')
for student in classonelist:
    print('  {:<15} last three scores: {}'.format(student[0]+',', student[1:]))
```

Output:

```
classonelist:
  Josh Hill,      last three scores: [0, 1, 2]
  Lisa Hale,      last three scores: [3, 4, 5]
  Max Wood,       last three scores: [6, 7, 8]
  Sally Jones,    last three scores: [9, 10, 11]
  David West,     last three scores: [12, 13, 14]
```